# WebCamTextureを使用して録画とデータ入力を同時に行いたい

Tags: ios, xcode, unity2d

Unityでの開発を行っております。

iPadでのネイティブのカメラを呼び出し、撮影・録画をしながらアプリ側で入力を行うことを考えております。
画面半分で撮影しているものを表示し、もう半分で入力ボタンなどのUI制御を行うことを考えております。

ネイティブのカメラを呼び出し、カメラ撮影しているものを画面上に表示することは出来ているのですが、こちら録画することが出来ておりません。
以下カメラ撮影時のコードになります。

```
public enum COMMON_WEB_CAMERA_STUTAS
{
    NOT_USER    = -2,
    NOT_DEVICES = -1,
    NONE        = 0,
    OK          = 1,
};

[SerializeField] private RawImage   _cameraUI = null;

private WebCamTexture   _webCamTexture  = null;
private COMMON_WEB_CAMERA_STUTAS _stutas = COMMON_WEB_CAMERA_STUTAS.NONE;

public setVideo()
{
    if( _cameraUI == null ) return;
    
    if( WebCamTexture.devices.Length == 0 )
    {
        _stutas = COMMON_WEB_CAMERA_STUTAS.NOT_DEVICES;
        Debug.Log( "There is no camera device" );
        return;
    }
    
    if( !Application.HasUserAuthorization( UserAuthorization.WebCam ) )
    {
        _stutas = COMMON_WEB_CAMERA_STUTAS.NOT_USER;
        return;
    }
    
    WebCamDevice userCameraDevice = WebCamTexture.devices[0];
    _webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture( userCameraDevice.name, Screen.width, Screen.height, 30 );
    _cameraUI.texture = _webCamTexture;
    _stutas = COMMON_WEB_CAMERA_STUTAS.OK;
}

public void onPlay()
{
    if( _webCamTexture != null )    _webCamTexture.Play();
}

public void onStop()
{
    if( _webCamTexture != null )    _webCamTexture.Stop();
}
```

画面のキャプチャではなく、撮影しているものだけを録画したいと考えておりますが、
方法ご存じでありましたら教えていただければと思います。

開発環境
Unity2020.3.1f1
Xcode12.5

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「録画する」と「録画とデータ入力を同時に行う」は分けて考えた方がよいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 基本的に現状ではWebCamDevice で撮影できている映像を録画できればと考えております。ただ、ネイティブカメラの呼び出しとはやりたいことが異なりますので、録画とデータ入力を同時に行うと記載させていただきました。